# How to alter ciphertext in python?

Tags: python, aes, bit, pycrypto

I am attempting to learn python and cryptography at the same time.

I am trying to alter the cipher text by a bit (or more) to see the effect it would have on my plaintext when decrypting.

For example:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import base64
import os

BLOCK_SIZE = 16
key = os.urandom(BLOCK_SIZE)

PADDING = '{'
pad = lambda s: s + (BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE) * PADDING

EncodeAES = lambda c, s: base64.b64encode(c.encrypt(pad(s)))
DecodeAES = lambda c, e: c.decrypt(base64.b64decode(e)).rstrip(PADDING)

cipher = AES.new(key)

# encode a string
encoded = EncodeAES(cipher, 'This is some text.')
print 'Encrypted string:', encoded

# decode the encoded string
decoded = DecodeAES(cipher, encoded)
print 'Decrypted string:', decoded
```

So I want to decrypt again except having modified the cipher text ("encoded") before decrypting.

Thanks.

Comment: This is already insecure. It's using the OS's random number generator, which may not be high enough quality for cryptography.

Comment: @CrazyPython urandom is perfectly fine for crypto (at least on linux).

Comment: @T.J. Welcome to Stack Overflow! What is your actual question? Do you just want to modify `encoded` before you use `DecodeAES()` and are wondering what the best approach to doing that could be?

Comment: @mech yes and thank you.

Comment: Spoiler: Changing one bit in an encrypted block will essentially change about 50% of the decrypted bits in that block.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of introducing some noise to the `encoded` string is to alter every nth character in it. You can play around with string manipulation to introduce more or less random noise (make the nth a random character, change it on every iteration, etc).

Add this function and imports somewhere before your code:

```
import string
import random

def noise_every_n(input, n, first=0):
    output = ""
    for i, c in enumerate(input, -first):
        if i % n == 0: # using ascii_letters and digits is just what came to mind, there's other ways to get random characters.
            output += random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits)
        else:
            output += c
    return output
```

Then call the following between `encode` and `decode`:

```
every_n = random.randint(3, 5) # or just set it to a small integer
encoded = noise_every_n(encoded, every_n)
```

The function above was adapted from [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13668865/2386185).