# even and uneven letter, TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python

```
def ul(a):
    if a %2 == 0:
        print(a.upper())
    else:
        print(a.lower())

ul(input())
```

I get following error:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

I want to write every even letter in uppercase and every uneven letter in lowercase

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: A string can't be even or odd. `%` applied to a string (on the left) is a formatting operator, not the modulus operator. Does "every even letter" mean "every character whose index in the input string is even", or does it mean something else?

Comment: `a` is a string. What do you expect the modulo of a string is?

Comment: What do you consider as an "even letter"? Would you consider ``'ü'`` to be even or odd? Would you consider ``'a'`` in ``'aaa'`` to be always even/odd or have a separate even/odd'ness depending on position?

Comment: yes, that's it: "every character whose index in the input string is even"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def ul(a):
    a = a.lower()
    if ord(a) %2 == 0:
        print(a.upper())
    else:
        print(a.lower())
```

if you want user to enter only Alphabets, then try this

```
def ul(a):
    if ord(a) >= 110 and ord(a) < 123:
        a = a.lower()
        if ord(a) %2 == 0:
            print(a.upper())
        else:
            print(a.lower())
     else:
         print("Please enter Alphabets only")
```

Comment: TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 17 found

Comment: As per your question, its only about a character, not string

Comment: @blubber123456789 - with above logic, you can create further code for strings as well. Try it yourself and if you are stuck any where, please come back here, we will help you

Answer (score 0):

What you are now doing with this function is check whether the input (a string) is divisible by 2. This is not really what you wanted to do and it raises an error because strings are not modulo divisible.

You should better loop through the indices of the input string to fill a second string with upper and lower case letters:

```
def ul(s):
    outstring = ''
    for i in range(len(s)): ## For each index of the string
        if i%2==0:
            outstring += s[i].upper()  ## Even indices become upper case
        else:
            outstring += s[i].lower()  ## Odd indices become lower case
    print(outstring)


ul(input("Enter a string: "))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get mode of string as I understand. You should use len(a).

```
def ul(a):
    if len(a) %2 == 0:
        print(a.upper())
    else:
        print(a.lower())

ul(input())
```

Answer (score 0):

Input will give you a string. You want to use the modulo operator %, which is exactly how you usually find the evenness of a number. So, you are on the right track!
What actually happens is that Python interprets your % as the format operator (probably has a fancy name).

```
number = 2
print("Number %d is this" % number)
>>> Number 2 is this
```

Strings in Python are immutable, so you can't just change the string that easily.

Try this [Replacing every 2nd character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50187485/replacing-every-2nd-character-in-a-string) , where you construct a new string by adding all the individual characters together.

```
def ul(word):
    new = []
    for i in range(len(word)):
        if i%2 == 0:
            new += word[i].upper()
    else:
        new += word[i].lower()
    print("".join(new))
```

This will go through the string character by character, transform the individual character based on if it is even or not, and then construct a list "new", that holds all the individual characters. In the end, just join it, so create a new string out of the list.

There are more pythonic ways to do this using list comprehension, but for now this is easier to read and understand.